# Wi-Fi disappears in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu

I have a problem that makes me crazy. I'm a newbie in Linux world, erased Win10, relocated on Kubuntu and I have a permanent problem: in unpredictable periods of time Wi-Fi is dropped down, any clicks on Wi-Fi icon don't show the list of networks around and only reboot can help. My wife has another laptop on Win10, she is connected to the same Wi-Fi point and everything is well — it's not the router problem.

KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-56-generic

What I've tried:

1. Reinstall drivers for Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 from Github
2. Reinstall all Ubuntu packages →

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```

   paste below into reinstall_all.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/bash   
   for pkg in dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '(dpkg|apt|mysql|mythtv)' ;  do apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done

   sudo chown root:root reinstall_all.sh
   sudo chmod 755 reinstall_all.sh
   sudo ./reinstall_all.sh
   ```
3. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

   but I have the same bug, help me, please.

SecureBoot is disabled

`sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't work

`sudo lshw -C network` shows:

```
 ​-network                  
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
        logical name: enp4s0
        version: 10
        serial: 54:e1:ad:c1:72:f2
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii  10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000b
 t-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1  04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multi
 cast=yes port=MII
        resources: irq:18 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f4204000-f4204fff memory:f4200000-
 f4203fff
   *-network
        description: Wireless interface
        product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
        vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
        logical name: wlp5s0
        version: 31
        serial: d4:6a:6a:df:05:13
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic  firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=
 192.168.50.57 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:132 memory:f4000000-f41fffff
```

`nmcli device show wlp5s0 | grep IP4.DNS` shows:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
```

`ifconfig` shows:

```
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         ether 54:e1:ad:c1:72:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
         RX packets 2014  bytes 149738 (149.7 KB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 2014  bytes 149738 (149.7 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
 wlp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.50.57  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
         inet6 fe80::c5b:e24:ce0d:5122  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether d4:6a:6a:df:05:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 66135  bytes 60494402 (60.4 MB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 1271  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 35370  bytes 6700045 (6.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

UPD.

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager -f

-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-11-06 00:29:55 EET. --
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5158] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): option wpad                 => ''
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5158] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed unknown -> bound
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5170] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5510] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5514] device (wlp5s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5519] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5539] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5541] policy: set 'Bifrost' (wlp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5547] device (wlp5s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1607792252.5561] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL

journalctl -u wpa_supplicant -f

-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-11-06 00:29:55 EET. --
дек 12 18:57:18 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
дек 12 18:57:18 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: WPS-PBC-ACTIVE
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with a8:5e:45:76:09:84 (SSID='Bifrost' freq=5200 MHz)
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: Trying to associate with a8:5e:45:76:09:84 (SSID='Bifrost' freq=5200 MHz)
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: Associated with a8:5e:45:76:09:84
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with a8:5e:45:76:09:84 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
дек 12 18:57:32 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 wpa_supplicant[832]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to a8:5e:45:76:09:84 completed [id=0 id_str=]

journalctl -p err

дек 12 00:56:31 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 [440388]: Failed to execute /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix: Exec format error
дек 12 00:56:31 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 [440385]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix failed with exit status 1.
дек 12 10:58:21 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 [440507]: Failed to execute /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix: Exec format error
дек 12 10:58:22 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 [440504]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wififix failed with exit status 1.
дек 12 11:02:40 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1390]: Error opening PCM device front:2: No such file or directory
дек 12 11:02:40 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1390]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
дек 12 11:02:40 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1390]: Error opening PCM device hw:1: No such file or directory
дек 12 11:02:40 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1390]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
-- Reboot --
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
дек 12 11:03:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: usb 1-4.1.4: device descriptor read/all, error -110
дек 12 11:03:43 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 sddm-helper[1085]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
дек 12 14:44:54 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1093]: Error opening PCM device hw:1: No such file or directory
дек 12 14:44:54 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1093]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
дек 12 14:45:13 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
дек 12 14:45:19 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
дек 12 14:45:23 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
дек 12 14:45:23 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to reset chip: -5
дек 12 14:45:23 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Could not init hif: -5
дек 12 14:45:23 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid 125bef18-d3b1-46af-9866-f90babe>
дек 12 14:45:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read firmware dump area: -16
дек 12 14:45:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
дек 12 14:45:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:30 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:30 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:30 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:30 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:30 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 14:45:30 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
-- Reboot --
дек 12 14:46:08 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
дек 12 14:46:08 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
дек 12 14:46:08 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
дек 12 14:46:10 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
дек 12 14:46:10 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
дек 12 14:46:10 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
дек 12 14:49:12 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 sddm-helper[1145]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
дек 12 18:56:00 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1171]: Error opening PCM device hw:1: No such file or directory
дек 12 18:56:00 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 pulseaudio[1171]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
дек 12 18:56:19 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
дек 12 18:56:25 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
дек 12 18:56:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
дек 12 18:56:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to reset chip: -5
дек 12 18:56:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Could not init hif: -5
дек 12 18:56:29 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid 8f3d1755-72fd-4a8c-9a26-2f4c9ab>
дек 12 18:56:35 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: failed to read firmware dump area: -16
дек 12 18:56:35 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
дек 12 18:56:35 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:35 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:36 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:36 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:36 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:36 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:36 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
дек 12 18:56:36 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 42949>
-- Reboot --
дек 12 18:57:14 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
дек 12 18:57:14 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: usb 1-4.1.4: language id specifier not provided by device, defaulting to English
дек 12 18:57:14 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
дек 12 18:57:14 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
дек 12 18:57:15 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
дек 12 18:57:15 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
дек 12 18:57:15 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
дек 12 18:57:27 zephyr-ThinkPad-E470 sddm-helper[1094]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try: `$ pkill -f wpa_supplicant`
Before running: `$ service network-manager restart`

I've seen similar issues. Sometimes it is a problem when the driver is not well supported, or configured incorrectly. The NetworkManager periodically performs a background routine in which it performs a background network scan, purges the connection and reconnects freshly. If its configured incorrectly, the NetworkManager performs this routine too frequently seeming like the connection gets dropped constantly.

Let's figure out what is actually going on with your system. We'll need to take a look at the system logs in `journactl`. Monitor the `NetworkManager`, `wpa_supplicant` logs by running:

`$ journalctl -u NetworkManager -f`
`$ journalctl -u wpa_supplicant -f`
And general system errors:
`$ journalctl -p err`

Post here the logs that you get during the disconnection error.

Comment: today this strange situation became again, I've tried to post here logs but moderator deleted my post. How can I share it with you?

Comment: Add it as and edit of your original question.

Comment: great idea! done! by the way, pkill -f wpa_supplicant and service network-manager restart didn't work

Comment: Did your issue start at 18:57 or before the reboot? If before the reboot, then you are not really showing the network logs of the relevant issue. It might be the case that your computer purges the **info logs** after each reboot. Your machine do stores the **error logs** after reboots though.

Comment: Your system errors are quite concerning though (Firmware crashed). I looked into the "Initramfs unpacking failed". That one could be related to the BIOS. Your SATA configuration should be set to ACHI.

Comment: thank you so much, I will try!